# How to send data from my website to my Arduino netshield

Tags: jquery, html, arduino

I want to for example turn LEDs on or off via website interface, but my main problem is that whenever I search for solutions every one is doing it via making the NetShield itself as the server and host the website from it, but I want to host the website on my own pc and when I click a button that action will send some data to the Arduino and I will read the data and turn on the LED.

I've tried with jQuery which is sending an HTTP POST request, but via close inspection the shield gives HTTP response 405 which after I read it seems that NetShield is not allowing modifying requests, so I've tried with HTTP GET but when I click the button nothing really goes to Arduino.

Btw everything about the network is correct and every port/firewall rule is open that it needs

Here is the HTML of the website:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>AgroSystem</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/res/IconRaster.png" type="image/png">
        <meta name="keywords" content="HTML, CSS, XML, XHTML, JavaScript, Agro, System, Agriculture, Zemedelie, Mashina, Auto, Network, Arduino, Better, Fast, Automatic, Farm, Farming">
        <meta name="author" content="Danislav Chengeliev">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="lib/jquery/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="src/script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <strong><h1>Лампи</h1></strong>
            <ul>
                <a href="" id="button-lamps-start"><li>Старт</li></a>
                <a href="" id="button-lamps-stop"><li>Стоп</li></a>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is my script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#button-lamps-start").click(function() {
        console.log("test");
        $.get("http://192.168.5.100:80/", "test");
    });
    $("#button-lamps-stop").click(() => {
        alert(10); //for testing purposes
    });
});
```

And here is the Arduino source:

```cpp
// TODO: Measure real values from moist sensor in real soil

#include <Wire.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
#include <Adafruit_TSL2561_U.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>

byte mac[] = {
  0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED
};

// Constructing objects
Adafruit_TSL2561_Unified tsl = Adafruit_TSL2561_Unified(TSL2561_ADDR_FLOAT, 1);
Adafruit_SSD1306 Display(128, 32, &Wire, -1);
IPAddress localip(192,168,5,100);
IPAddress remoteip(192, 168, 5, 111);
EthernetClient client;

sensors_event_t event;

#define LightSensorLED 22

#define FanInStartBtn 23
#define FanInStopBtn 25

#define FanOutStartBtn 27
#define FanOutStopBtn 29

#define FanInLED 28
#define FanOutLED 36

#define moistSensor A8

#define waterLevel A9
#define chemicalLevelSpray A10
#define chemicalLevel A11

#define rainSensor A12

void setup() {
  //temp for debugging
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // Pinouts
  pinMode(LightSensorLED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(FanInLED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(FanOutLED, OUTPUT);

  // Pinins
  pinMode(FanInStartBtn, INPUT);
  pinMode(FanInStopBtn, INPUT);
  pinMode(FanOutStartBtn, INPUT);
  pinMode(FanOutStopBtn, INPUT);
  pinMode(moistSensor, INPUT);
  pinMode(waterLevel, INPUT);

  // Init ethernet
  Ethernet.begin(mac, remoteip);
  Serial.println("beg");
  Ethernet.setLocalIP(localip);
  Serial.println("set ip");
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
  if (!client.connect(remoteip, 80)) {
    Serial.println("noo");
    do {
      Serial.println("try again");
      client.connect({192,168,5,111}, 80);
    } while (!client.connected());
  }
Serial.println("con");
  // Init displays
  Display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, 0x3C);

  // Init sensors
  tsl.begin();
  tsl.enableAutoRange(true);
  tsl.setIntegrationTime(TSL2561_INTEGRATIONTIME_13MS);
}
#define w(x) client.println(x);
void loop() {
  lightSensor(LightSensorLED, 10);
  FanControls(FanInStartBtn, FanInStopBtn, FanInLED);
  FanControls(FanOutStartBtn, FanOutStopBtn, FanOutLED);
  delay(250);
  if (client.available()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < client.available(); i++) {
      Serial.println(client.read());    // THIS SHOULD DUMP ALL THE BYETS FROM THE NETSHIELD TO SERIAL MONITOR
    }
  }
  //Serial.print((817 - analogRead(moistSensor)) / 4); Serial.println("%"); //not finished
  //Serial.println(analogRead(waterLevel) / 6); //not finished
  //Serial.print(analogRead(chemicalLevelSpray) / 6); Serial.println("%"); //not finished
  //Serial.print(analogRead(chemicalLevel) / 6); Serial.println("%"); //not finished
  //Serial.print(analogRead(rainSensor)); //not finished / not for reading but for turning lamp
}

void FanControls(unsigned const char FanStartPort, unsigned const char FanStopPort, unsigned const char FanLEDPort) {
  if (!digitalRead(FanStartPort)) {
    digitalWrite(FanLEDPort, 0);
  } else if (!digitalRead(FanStopPort)) {
    digitalWrite(FanLEDPort, 1);
  }
}

void lightSensor(unsigned const char portNumber, unsigned const int value) {
  // Retrieves the data from the sensor
  tsl.getEvent(&event);

  // Check if its night and turn on the lamps
  if (event.light <= value) {
    digitalWrite(portNumber, 0);
  } else if (event.light > value) {
    digitalWrite(portNumber, 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Post arduino program also.

Comment: @Pradeep Yes, sorry for that, I've updated the thread

Answer (score 1):

There are two different solutions if you want to send data from an HTML Page (Web server) to Arduino:

1. Implement a simple web server on Arduino side that accepts HTTP requests
2. Use aRest to create a simple API to invoke from the HTML side

I've written a simple tutorial on my blog to cover how to use aRest with Arduino with an example like yours: https://www.survivingwithandroid.com/arduino-rest-api-iot/

If you prefer to use a Web server you can give a look at this example showing how to build a simple Web server to accept HTTP requests https://www.survivingwithandroid.com/connect-android-arduino-using-http-web-server/

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter where the website is located (on Arduino, on your local PC or wherever), but Arduino still has to act as a server to listen to incoming events.
Arduino is now setup as a client (`EthernetClient client;`), which means: sending data *to* a server (which isn't there).

Make it [a server](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/EthernetServer) to receive events.

Comment: Actually it matters because i dont have all the memory in the world and the website isnt small, but eventually i figured it out by my own. Ive made a web server and had arduino send http requests to it.

Comment: There is a difference between a website and a web server. The web server only listens for incoming events and can (not necessary!) respond with a website. The advantage of a server over a client is, that a server only waits for a request, while the client constantly asks for information.